# Scraping big basket products failing

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, e-commerce, cheerio

I am trying to get all the products of bigbasket.com website for a particular web search.
I am using the URL: https://www.bigbasket.com/ps/?q=tata for now to get all the products for the search query tata.

```
exports.getBBPrices = (req, res, next) => {
let searchQuery = req.query.search;
searchQuery = searchQuery.split(' ').join('+');
console.log(searchQuery);
var options = {
    headers: {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36'},
    method: 'GET'
}
url = `https://www.bigbasket.com/ps/?q=tata`;
const result = [];
process.setMaxListeners(15)
request(url, options, function(err, response, html){
    if(!err) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        // ... furhter processing
    } else {
        console.log('error', err);
    }
});
```

}

I am getting the following error in the console.

(node:16080) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 pipe listeners added to [Request]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
error Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop https://www.bigbasket.com/ps/?q=tata
at Redirect.onResponse (C:\my_space\projects\get prices\node_modules\request\lib\redirect.js:98:27)
at Request.onRequestResponse (C:\my_space\projects\get prices\node_modules\request\request.js:986:22)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:311:20)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:603:27)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:476:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)

Can any one please help me solve the issue.

Comment: Let's say the server is setting a session cookie in the response header and redirecting to the same url. Request won't set the cookie and you'll be stuck in a redirect loop.

Comment: is there a solution to avoid that and get a proper response?

Comment: look into the cookiejar option for that library.